# Phantom LaunchDaemon process (OSX)

Tags: macos, launchd

I created a LaunchDaemon a while back to start a shell script I had written.  It looks like someone deleted the .plist from /Library/LaunchDaemons.

In my system logs (/var/logs/system.log), i see that my system is constantly trying to launch that shell script, but, neither the script or the plist exist anymore.

I can't figure out how to get the system to stop trying to launch the script.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you restarted the computer? LaunchDaemons are loaded at system startup, so removing the .plist file after that doesn't kill them item (in fact, you need the .plist to *unload* the item after startup with `sudo launchctl unload`...).

Comment: It worked!   Too simple.  If you want to make an answer out of that... I'll accept it :)  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaunchDaemons are loaded at system startup, and once loaded they're kept in memory so removing the .plist file doesn't do anything. If the file were still there, you could unload it with `sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.whatever.plist`, but that does require the file. Restarting the computer will reload the LaunchDaemons, effectively removing the phantom job.

After I wrote my original comment, I found another way that (I think) would've worked: you can remove a LaunchDaemon without the file by its label with `sudo launchctl remove com.whatever`